# Vector bundle and principal bundle

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

First, why the vector bundle, structured from principal bundle, has structure group $G$ ?

Second, how to prove the principal $G$-bundle, structured from vector bundle, is principal bundle according the Definition 2.3.3 ?

Picture below is from the 65 of Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*. In fact ,I think the definition 2.3.3 is not a good definition.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: What do you mean for "vector bundle structured from principal bundle"?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos  I mean how to get a vector bundle from pincipal bundle.

Comment: It is all explained in the text: what do not you understand?

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake in the text: _the structure group of_ $G\times_G\mathbb{V}$ **is** $GL(\mathbb{V})$!

Comment: @Armandoj18eos  Are you Jost ?

Comment: No: I'm not [Jürgen Jost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%BCrgen_Jost)!